# How can I to restrict users from seeing some folders and files under rootPath of xtype pathfield of CQ AEM?

Tags: aem, jcr, xtype

This is a question about the interesting world of AEM.

In dialog box, I want user to allow to select any sub folders and files except certain files or folders.

My jcr refContent in the xml looks like below. I want user to be able to select and also see some folders under /content/mainfolder AND not see some folders & filder there.
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/widgets-api/index.html

I do not seem to find any solution. Any ideas/help please is greatly appreciated.

```
<refContent
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        fieldDescription="Mandatory field. Select a page"
        fieldLabel="Content reference"
        itemCls="mandatory-field"
        name="./refContent"
        key="refContent"
        componentClass="refContent"
        rootPath="/content/mainfolder"
        xtype="pathfield"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @SharathMadappa. I am looking at your example. It may be the one.

Answer (score 0):

This can be managed by providing correct permission to users. For folders which you dont want user to access, remove read permission for this user. Hope this will help.

Comment: If you remove read persmission, will they still see the folders?

Comment: However it does not solve my problem. Because if I remove read access, they will not be able to the pages. FOr the particular componet, they should not be accessing certain pages ...For other components they should be able to..

Comment: In this case i am wondering if you need to write custom code to achieve this behavior. kind of an extn of pathfield xtype which also perform a permission check before showing page hierarchy.